# migrate from get-qaduser to get-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have setup my script to disable inactive user in my Win 2003 AD server using Quest's AD tool GET-QADUSER, and now I am going to migrate AD to Win 2008 R2. Since there is Active Directory module and [Quest's tool](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) is no longer free to download (is that?), I am going to migrate to GET-ADUSER.

I am converting from:

```
Foreach ($ou in $searchBase) {
#$inactUsr += @(Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $ou -Enabled -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -NotLoggedOnFor $inactiveDays -CreatedBefore $creationCutoff -SizeLimit $sizeLimit | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonTimeStamp,Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Sort-Object Name)
}
```

to:

```
$inactUsr += @(Get-ADUser -SearchRoot $ou -Filter 'enabled -eq $true -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False' -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonTimeStamp,Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Select Name,SamAccountName,@{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}},Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Sort Name)
```

I am almost there and leave only -NotLogonFor (which select user that not logon for certain days) and -CreatedBefore (which give a grace period for newly created ID). I want to select ID NotLogon for 30 days and DO NOT want ID created less than 30 days.

Appreciate if anyone can let me know whether there is a built-in properties or any manual method to achieve that.

---

Edited:
I have the CreatedBefore solved by:

```
$inactUsrdraft += @(Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter 'enabled -eq $true -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and whenCreated -le $CreationCutOff' -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonTimeStamp,Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Select Name,SamAccountName,@{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}},Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Sort Name)
```

:)

Now I need only need to filter ID not logon more than 30 days.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$LastLogonCutoff = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-30)
```

That's midnight 30 days ago.  If you want it to the second, use `(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)`.

Followed by changing the `-Filter` to include:

```
`-and (LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $LastLogonCutoff)`
```

Also beware that the `LastLogonTimeStamp` property is [not very accurate](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx).  Laptop logins off-network that use saved credentials won't trigger, I believe.  If you don't have "Wait for network" enabled, clients might never actually update this value, IIRC.

Comment: Hi Bacon,
Yes I just figured that out as well, just follow same concept of CreationCutOff :)
We do not have laptop that connected to our domain so no concern on that. And yea I'm also aware of the delay of LastLogonTimeStamp sync between DCs. My complete script will actually continue to retrieve LastLogon date of these IDs from each DCs, and I believe that's the most updated logon info I can get in AD.
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hi, I'm having an additional question i'm thinking whether I can get help again instead of open a new thread.
I have SET-ADUSER command below:
Set-ADUser $user.SamAccountName -Description "$TodaysDate - Account Disabled due to Inactivity - $($user.Description)" -Enabled $False | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $DisabledOU.

all working fine except the MOVE-ADOBJECT. Do SET-ADUSER allow pipe in this way?

Comment: Only able to get MOVE-ADOBJECT to work with GET-ADUSER and not SET-ADUSER. So make me without a choice but to use 2 lines of command.
Thank you.

Comment: @nlks Add the `-Passthru` common parameter to `Set-AdUser` to return an object for the affected user.

Comment: Yes that's work! I'm still learning, once again thank you for your guide.

Comment: Hi I have an update on this today as I notice that the account that never logon will not be listed. I checked the $inactUsr these users having LastLogonTimeStamp as blank, not sure is it due to my date conversion @{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}}. Then by using filter -and (LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $LastLogonCutoff), I am not sure "blank" can be less than date(?). Do you have any idea?

Comment: @nlks As far as I'm aware, a user account that's never logged in would have a value of null or have the property at all in LDAP.  That is, what you're seeing is the designed behavior of Active Directory.  You should be able to query them with a filter of `(LastLogonTimeStamp -ne "*")`... although maybe that's returning all users... hm.

Comment: @nlks Ah, I got it.  `(LastLogonTimeStamp -notlike "*")`.